# How to load images to a page as soon as they are loaded from a folder in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm using the AdaptiveGridView to load a list of images from a folder onto the page. my question is how can i load an image as soon as it's become ready and not have to wait for the entire list of images to be processed.
Here's my code:
C#

```
 public class Images
        {
            public ImageSource ImageURL { get; set; }
            public string ImageText { get; set; }
        }

        private List<Images> ImageCollection;

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ImageCollection = new List<Images>();
            // pick a folder
            var folderPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker();
            folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
            var folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
            var filesList = await folder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.DefaultQuery, new string[] { ".jpg", ".png", ".jpeg" })).GetFilesAsync();
            for (int i = 0; i < filesList.Count; i++)
            {
                StorageFile imagefile = filesList[i];
                BitmapImage bitmapimage = new BitmapImage();
                using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await imagefile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
                {
                    bitmapimage.SetSource(stream);
                }

                ImageCollection.Add(new Images()
                {
                    ImageURL = bitmapimage,
                    ImageText = filesList[i].Name
                });
                countPhotos.Text = i.ToString() + "out of" + filesList.Count.ToString();

            }
            AdaptiveGV.ItemsSource = ImageCollection;

        }
```

XAML:

```
<Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="PhotosList">
            <Grid>
                <Image Source="{Binding ImageURL}"
                       Stretch="UniformToFill"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center">

                </Image>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>
    <StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="click me" Click="Button_Click">

        </Button>
        <TextBlock Name="countPhotos">

        </TextBlock>
        <ScrollViewer>

            <UWPToolkit:AdaptiveGridView x:Name="AdaptiveGV"
                                                 ItemHeight="300" DesiredWidth="500"
                                                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PhotosList}">

            </UWPToolkit:AdaptiveGridView>
        </ScrollViewer>



    </StackPanel>
```

I tired moving the  `AdaptiveGV.ItemsSource = ImageCollection;` inside of the for loop but that slowed down the process and  I dont think its the best way to accomplish what i'm trying to do here. any other suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an `ObservableCollection` instead of a `List`. You could then assign the collection to the `ItemsSource` property before adding the images. The `ObservableCollection` notifies the UI about changes, e.g. about added elements.

Besides that, you should also use the `async BitmapImage.SetSourceAsync()` method.

```
public class ImageItem
{
    public ImageSource Image { get; set; }
    public string ImageText { get; set; }
}

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var imageCollection = new ObservableCollection<ImageItem>();
    AdaptiveGV.ItemsSource = imageCollection;

    for ...
    {
        ...
        await bitmapimage.SetSourceAsync(stream); 

        ...
        imageCollection.Add(new ImageItem()
        {
            Image = bitmapimage,
            ImageText = filesList[i].Name
        });
    }
}
```

Note also that I've replaced the (confusing) names `Images` and `ImageURL` by
`ImageItem` and `Image`. You would have to change the `Image.Source` Binding in the DataTemplate to this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Image}"
```

---

The next step could be to create a view model that holds the `ObservableCollection<ImageItem>` as a (read-only) property:

```
public class ViewModel 
{
    public ObservableCollection<ImageItem> ImageCollection { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<ImageItem>();

    public async Task LoadImages(StorageFolder folder)
    {
        var queryOptions = new QueryOptions(
            CommonFileQuery.DefaultQuery, new string[] { ".jpg", ".png", ".jpeg" });
        var files = await folder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions).GetFilesAsync();

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            using (var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
            {
                BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                await image.SetSourceAsync(stream);

                ImageCollection.Add(new ImageItem
                {
                    Image = image,
                    ImageText = file.Name
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You would assign the Page's `DataContext` to an instance of the view model in the Page constructor and call the `LoadImages()` method on Button Click:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new ViewModel();
}

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var folderPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker();
    folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
    var folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();

    if (folder != null)
    {
        await ((ViewModel)DataContext).LoadImages(folder);
    }
}
```

In XAML, you would bind the ItemsSource property to the ImageCollection property like this:

```
<UWPToolkit:AdaptiveGridView ...
    ItemsSource="{Binding ImageCollection}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PhotosList}" />
```

Comment: Thanks soooooooo much <3 <3 <3